# Is there a word or short phrase to describe a movie that wins many awards?

Tags: single-word-requests, cinema

Like "award reaper" or "award sweeper". I know they may not be correct so I need a right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An award sweeper, though rare, isn't [unheard-of](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=SZZyyL2di9cC&pg=PA257&lpg=PA257&dq=%22academy%20award%20sweeper%22&source=bl&ots=56Izo8YuQC&sig=NrcvaIw5AXjseCDgBKHACtFHNmg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=uTmeVdXsOIOiugTx7KewDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22academy%20award%20sweeper%22&f=false). It should be understood.

You can refer to a movie as being **critically lauded**.

In a broader sense, the phrase **[critics' darling](http://kafe.com/news/030030-boyhood-is-critics-darling/)** is used. But these may or may not imply awards.

Answer (score 14):

**Award-winning films**
Google Books produces [1,130 results](https://www.google.it/search?q=Award-winning%20films&oq=Award-winning%20films&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22Award-winning%20films%22&tbm=bks)

> - Eighty **prize-winning films** of the 1930s are discussed in detail, with complete cast and technical credits, background notes, etc.
> - Howard has served as an executive producer as well on a number of **award- winning films** and television shows...
> - She is also an accomplished filmmaker who has made a series of **award-winning films** including Ellis Island (1981)

For **award-winning movies**, Google Books produces [896 results](https://www.google.it/search?q=Award-winning%20films&oq=Award-winning%20films&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=%22Award-winning%20movies%22)

> - These include such Broadway successes as *Brigadoon* (1947), *Paint Your Wagon* (1951), *My Fair Lady* (1956), and *Camelot* (1960), and the **Academy-Award winning movies** *Gigi* (1958) and *My Fair Lady* (1964)
> - *Funny Girl* and *Meet the Packers*; or by her genius as a composer in songs like the **Academy Award-winning** *Evergreen*; or by her screenwriting, directing and production skills in the **multi-award winning movies**, *Yentl* and *Prince of Tides*

Comment: To me, "award-winning" is the most idiomatic way to describe a movie that has actually won awards.  While "critically acclaimed" or "critically lauded" movies are certainly "good", those phrases mean something entirely different than "award-winning".  In fact, many times movies that critics love get snubbed by the authorities who are in charge of handing out the awards.

Answer (score 13):

**Critically Acclaimed**

> "That has received generally good reviews from a number of critics
>   Although it was critically acclaimed, the album wasn't a commercial success."

[Source](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/critically_acclaimed)

Comment: It's a useful phrase, but not really the same - if most critics have said universally positive things about a movie, it's "critically acclaimed" even if it never actually won a single award.

Answer (score 2):

The ugly construction **multi-award winning** (both with and without a second hyphen after "award") appears to be used quite widely. Google turns up many hits, such as this [obituary of Harold Pinter](http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2008/dec/26/harold-pinter-death-tributes) or this [press release from Qatar Airways](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/multi-award-winning-qatar-airways-wins-airline-of-the-year-honour-at-2015-skytrax-airline-awards-507684221.html).

Answer (score 0):

The common phrase for a movie (or book or song or whatever) that has won one or more awards is "award-winning".

I can't think of any commonly-used phrase for a movie that has won many awards, as opposed to just one.

If a movie wins awards in many categories of a single competition, we say it "swept the awards". But I've never heard such a movie called an "award-sweeping movie" or using any other adjective phrase other than "award-winning".

Answer (score -1):

Such a movie may be called a **blockbuster.**

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blockbuster

Comment: Nah, this just means it made money.